# Customize WP listify theme & WP Job Manager plugin to support custom type listings in wordpress pages

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using a wordpress theme called listify. WP Job Manager is a required plugin. On my website, I need two kinds of listings. One listing for the employers [employers listing] and another one for the vacancies posted by those employers [vacancy listing]. The WP Job Manager plugin doesn't seem to support multiple listings in one installation. If you can write a separate custom page (one not provided with the theme) for the vacancies, how would you get to define those vacancies under an employer. What other plugin alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 0):

As your question is related to a specific plugin, I would recommend you to contact the plugin author first. I am not used the listify or WP JOb Manager myself but I am sure you can achieve what you wanted using WP custom Post type and custom fields.

If you need any specific help reference custom post type or fields, post a new question.